# Which advantages do the manuscript repositories for our community have?

Tags: open-source

The question here arises from the fact that we currently have two options:

1. [Optimization Online](http://www.optimization-online.org/)
2. [ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/list/math.OC/current) Optimization and control

Which advantages does each one of them (and others if not included) provide? OO is provided by the Mathematical Optimization Society, while ArXiv is provided by Cornell University.

Comment: I am [voting to close](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/dont-forget-to-close-and-reopen-vote) because this question is primarily opinion-based. If you want to know specific information about these repositories, the question would be less subjective (but possibly not on topic). I think this is actually a great topic, but just doesn't fit well with SE's Q&A format (as opposed to a discussion forum).

Comment: We had a discussion on meta about whether resource comparisons are on-topic, and the consensus seems to be that there has to be a specific requirement or requirements that the resource must accomplish to be on-topic. Currently you don't seem to have any requirements, just asking which of two tools is better, which is opinion-based. See [this answer](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-resource-recommendations-be-on-topic/7#7).

Comment: Even though the question was not asked in compliance with the no opinions allowed rule which some people (not me) want to enforce, i think people can give thoughtful answers discussing the various pros and cons of the presented options.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Also, I think the question can be edited and put back. For example, it would be nice to discuss which one is more `usual' to submit a Game Theory side of OR paper. ( I am also curious)..

Comment: Is there any rule or societal convention against posting preprints in multiple locations?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone [What are the pros and cons of submitting same paper to more than one open repository?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1510/106489)

Comment: I like the edited question a bit more, and no longer think it should be closed. It seems I can't retract my close vote, but if the question gets closed, I will vote to reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which advantages does each one (arXiv vs. OO) of them (and others if not included) provide?

The arXiv site has more, and an extensive review process. It is [not without controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv#Controversy).

The Optimization Online site is supported by the Mathematical Optimization Society (MOS), an international organization dedicated to the promotion and the maintenance of high professional standards in the subject of mathematical optimization. While they check that the author's contact information is correct they do not usually evaluate the report for quality or mathematical correctness.

---

- **[arXiv](https://arxiv.org/about)** has almost 21,458 submissions about [Optimization and Control](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=%22math.OC%22&terms-0-field=all&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=exclude&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first) (the subject matter asked about by user David Bernal), it also has:

  - 19,273 (cs.AI) submissions about [Artificial Intelligence](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=%22cs.AI%22&terms-0-field=all&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=exclude&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first)
  - 35,467 (cs.LG) submissions and 27,088 (stat.ML) submission about [Machine Learning](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=%22cs.LG%22&terms-0-field=all&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=exclude&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first) (some overlap)
  - 23,670 (stats.*) submissions [total](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-field=all&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-statistics=y&classification-include_cross_list=exclude&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first)

  [Policy](https://arxiv.org/help/moderation) (partial quote):

  "Why does arXiv moderate submissions?

  arXiv is an openly accessible, moderated repository for scholarly papers in specific scientific disciplines. Material submitted to arXiv is expected to be of interest, relevance, and value to those disciplines. arXiv reserves the right to reject or reclassify any submission.

  ...

  arXiv policies that could lead to the removal of a submission are:

  - Unrefereeable content. arXiv only accepts submissions in the form of an article that would be refereeable by a conventional publication venue. Papers that do not contain original or substantive research, including undergraduate research, course projects, and research proposals, news, or information about political causes (even those with potential special interest to the academic community) may be removed. Papers that contain inflammatory or fictitious content, papers that use highly dramatic and misrepresentative titles/abstracts/introductions, or papers in need of significant review and revision may be removed.

  ...

  - Rights to submit material. Submissions to arXiv must be the author’s original work, and users must have the right to grant the rights contained in the selected license. Users must ensure the submission does not, to the best of their knowledge, infringe upon anyone's copyright. Users should not submit comments by referees. Users should not submit plagiarized material.
  - Excessive submission rate. Articles submitted to arXiv must be of refereeable quality, and there is a practical limit to the rate at which appropriate, independent submissions can be produced by any one person. Moderators may request that a particular author limit their submission rate if this author has a history of many submissions to inappropriate areas or of doubtful refereeability.

  Who are arXiv moderators?

  arXiv moderators are volunteers who are experts in their fields and in the types of submissions that are appropriate for their subject classifications. They evaluate based on the content of the submission and the policies of arXiv. Moderators consider the submissions to arXiv as privileged information, as they would with a paper being refereed for a journal."

  [arXiv moderators](https://arxiv.org/moderators) are approved by their discipline-level [advisory committees](https://arxiv.org/help/scientific_ad_board#advisory_committees) and by arXiv staff. In addition, arXiv has links at the bottom of each paper which say "Which authors of this paper are endorsers?". That link has a link to: "[Why isn't a Person 'Registered as an Author?'](https://arxiv.org/help/not-registered)" and "[The arXiv endorsement system](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement)":

  "Why does arXiv require endorsement?

  arXiv is distinct from the web as a whole, because arXiv contains exclusively scientific content. The endorsement system verifies that arXiv contributors belong to the scientific community in a fair and sustainable way that can scale with arXiv's future growth.

  arXiv is an openly accessible, moderated repository for scholarly papers in specific scientific disciplines. Material submitted to arXiv is expected to be of interest, relevance, and value to those disciplines. Endorsement is a necessary but not sufficient condition to have papers accepted in arXiv; arXiv reserves the right to reject or reclassify any submission.

  The endorsement system ensures that arXiv content is relevant to current research at much lower cost than conventional peer-reviewed journals, so we can continue to offer free access to the scientific community and the general public. Although our system may be imperfect, people who fail to get endorsement are still free to post articles on their (own) web site or to submit their publications to (other) peer-reviewed journals."

  ...
- [Elsevier](https://www.elsevier.com/about/this-is-elsevier) - Elsevier has 140 years of experience in curation and verification. 75,382 editorial board members and more than 20,000 editors in academia and over 1.3m reviewers covering hundreds of disciplines.

  [Submission Guidelines](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/discrete-applied-mathematics/0166-218x/guide-for-authors) and [Quality Statement](https://www.elsevier.com/physical-sciences-and-engineering/mathematics/journals):

  Elsevier receives over 40,000 annual submissions to our mathematical sciences journals. Of these, more than  10,000 articles are accepted for publication, resulting in an average acceptance rate of 25%.

  We provide full text to frequently used mathematics services like MathSciNet®, ZentralBlatt, and NUMDAM. We link and produce metadata which is shared with the major abstracting and indexing services, and we improve search engine optimization, so that your research can be easily found.

  Their "[Decision Science](https://www.elsevier.com/catalog?producttype=journals&cat0=27384&cat1=&sort=datedesc)" category indexes the following Operations Research journals, and other journals of publications related to Operations Research:

  Subject           -           Title

  - [Control Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_engineering) - [Automatica](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/automatica)
  - [OR/MS](https://www.igi-global.com/dictionary/analytics-for-nonprofits/39434) - [Computers & Operations Research](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/computers-and-operations-research)
  - [Decision Support Systems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/decision-support-systems/about/aims-and-scope) - [Decision Support Systems and Electronic Commerce](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/decision-support-systems)
  - [Applied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_mathematics) and [Discreet Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics) - [Discrete Applied Mathematics](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/discrete-applied-mathematics)
  - [OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_research) - [European Journal of Operational Research](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/european-journal-of-operational-research)
  - [Game Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) - [Games and Economic Behavior](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/games-and-economic-behavior)
  - [Forecasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forecasting) - [International Journal of Forecasting](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/international-journal-of-forecasting)
  - [More next edit]

  Journals **touching on** Operations Research:

  - [Engineering Applications of Artificial Intelligence](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/engineering-applications-of-artificial-intelligence)
  - [Fuzzy Sets and Systems](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/fuzzy-sets-and-systems)
  - Pay to Publish (any discipline, including OR) - [Heliyon](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/heliyon)
  - [International Journal of Information Management](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/international-journal-of-information-management)

- The [Canadian Operations Research Society](https://www.cors.ca/?q=content/infor) publishes **[INFOR](https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/tinf20)**, the "Information Systems and Operational Research" journal.

  The INFORS journal has partial open access, and a helpful [FAQ webpage](https://authorservices.taylorandfrancis.com/frequently-asked-questions/) for people wanting information about how to get published and [choosing a journal](https://authorservices.taylorandfrancis.com/category/choosing-a-journal/). There are few articles, searching for "[optimization](https://www.tandfonline.com/action/doSearch?field1=AllField&text1=Optimization&SeriesKey=tinf20)" returns 654 results, 10 per page. There are only the simplest of search options, and using Google for the same search, "[optimization](https://www.google.com/search?ei=TYgCXaDeO6-Ak-4PucmIkAY&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.tandfonline.com%2Ftoc%2Ftinf20%20%22optimization%22&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.tandfonline.com%2Ftoc%2Ftinf20%20%22optimization%22)", produces 262 results; so there's no way around their search engine's interface with another tool to obtain more results.

  [Policy](https://www.tandfonline.com/action/journalInformation?journalCode=tinf20): "Canadian Operational Research Society (CORS) and our publisher Taylor & Francis make every effort to ensure the accuracy of all the information (the "Content") contained in our publications. However, Canadian Operational Research Society (CORS) and our publisher Taylor & Francis, our agents, and our licensors make no representations or warranties whatsoever as to the accuracy, completeness, or suitability for any purpose of the Content. Any opinions and views expressed in this publication are the opinions and views of the authors, and are not the views of or endorsed by Canadian Operational Research Society (CORS) and our publisher Taylor & Francis. The accuracy of the Content should not be relied upon and should be independently verified with primary sources of information."
- **[Netlib Repository](http://www.netlib.org/)** has 62 results for "[optimization](http://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/search.pl)" and while I wouldn't call it a "manuscript repository" it certainly is a repository of source code often referred to in (and developed by authors of) various papers. See the [Master Index](http://www.netlib.org/master/expanded_liblist.html) for more information.

  Their "[Guide to Available Mathematical Software](http://www.netlib.org/bib/gams.html)" (GAMS) is a cross-index and virtual repository of mathematical and statistical software components of use in computational science and engineering.

  Netlib has a respectable [list of editors and administrators](http://www.netlib.org/editors.html) but their exact criteria for publication isn't easy to find.
- **[Optimization Online](http://www.optimization-online.org/index.html)** has almost [7000](http://www.optimization-online.org/cgi-bin/search.cgi) submissions about optimization and related topics.

  [Policy](http://www.optimization-online.org/policy.html): "Papers are screened to ensure their relevance by one of the coordinators for the category selected by the submitting author as the principal category. The acceptance/rejection decision of a coordinator is final. Coordinators check that the submission details given by the authors are all present and correct and that the submitted files are readable. They do not usually evaluate the report for quality or mathematical correctness. Consequently, we make no claim about quality or correctness of the reports on the site. Optimization Online reserves the right in its sole discretion to remove accepted papers from the repository if complaints are received regarding their accuracy or authenticity."
- **[viXra](http://vixra.org/)** - Not to be confused with [arXiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv#Controversy), it accepts submissions [without requiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ViXra) authors to have an academic affiliation and without any threshold for quality.

[Note: I believe that this answers the question, as-is, but I will return to add more in the days ahead; as time permits.]

Disclaimer: Short quotes are almost all the information that is provided on their website, the lengthy quote (for arXiv) is considerably less than complete. See links for more info.

Comment: @Rob I meant no offense or backhandedness.

Comment: The question is not "give me a list of viXra sites" nor "give me a list of journals", and I've not answered as though it was.

Comment: @Rob I thought Michael Trick’s comments were constructive and not backhanded either, fwiw.